# Loan modelling using Opensource risk engine (ORE)

Tags: modeling

The problem is to calculate the cash flow schedule for a simple fixed rate loan where principal amortization periodicity is not equal to interest payment periodicity. For example, amortization is every 6 months and interest is paid every month.
The key difficulty in implementing this via TradeType = Bond is that the ORE will pay interest on each amortization date

Has anyone solved a similar task?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question: are there some dates where some principal is paid, but not interest - this happens in practice, and is hard to do in many libraries - or just some dates where interest is paid and zero principal is paid?

Comment: The first case - there are some dates where some principal is paid, but not interest

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear. Yes, it's pretty common with loans, but many libraries, including Quantlib,  which ORE uses heavily,don't bother implementing this feature because it's tricky: the interest accrued over a period duing which the outstanding principal varies. I mentioned it here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/58919/understanding-loans-with-a-dynamic-principal/58922#58922

Comment: @DimitriVulis thank you for the answer. It's very sad

Comment: You may find these earlier discussions helpful https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/72029  https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/48613

Comment: I don't see this in https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues?q=is%3Aissue , so someone may want to add it.